# Booting from CD in CentOS

Tags: centos, grub

I am trying to modify the grub boot manager in my CentOS machine so that it can boot from a CD-rom. The method I am most familiar with (and the method that all of my Google searches tell me to do) involve modifying the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file. Unfortunately, the folder `/etc/grub.d` doesn't seem to exist. Creating it and adding the file isn't helping, either. Does CentOS grub do something differently to other systems, or is this something that grub has changed recently? What should I be doing instead?

Comment: @Christopher: The boot manager doesn't give me the option... It simply lists CentOS and no image, even though the image is bootable. I see `grub.conf`, but I've always worked with the scripts in `grub.d` (via e.g. a menuentry command), and can't seem to figure out the syntax used in the `grub.conf` file.

Comment: The linux operating system (CentOS) does not do the booting.  It is your BIOS/EFI that does the booting, and it is there you tell it to boot from "DVD" or whichever disk.  Grub happens after the hard drive is already "booted", or once the DVD/CD has "booted" and the GRUB program contained on the DVD is executed.

Comment: Once Grub (grand unified boot loader) is running, it will then *load* whatever operating system (CentOS, Windows, whatever) it was configured to do.